# How do I use resource dictionary to remove border surrounding drop down Menu Items in WPF Menu

Tags: wpf, xaml, drop-down-menu, resourcedictionary

There is a white border surrounding my menu items (option 1, option 2, option 3) when shown in the menu dropdown.  How can I remove the border from showing? I have tried to match the border brush color for the menu items to the menu but the white border continues to show. Below is a picture of my 3 menu items surrounded by a white border I am trying to remove.

[image]

Here is the Resource Dictionary I am using for the Menu:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleWPFApp.ResourceDictionaries">

    <Style   TargetType="Menu">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"  Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="SkyBlue"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
    </Style>
    <Style   TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"  Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="SkyBlue"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
     </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Here is the XAML for the Menu:

```
<Menu VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="6">
    <MenuItem Header="Conversions">
        <MenuItem Name="Option1MenuItem" Header="Option 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300"
                  Click="Option1MenuItem_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Name="Option2MenuItem" Header="Option 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300"
                  Click="Option2MenuItem_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Name="Option3MenuItem3" Header="Option 3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300"
                  Click="Option3MenuItem_Click"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just FYI. +1. Thank you for providing such a well-formatted question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing thin border around the menuitems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281529/removing-thin-border-around-the-menuitems)